# How to use HSQLDB transfer tool

Tags: hsqldb, in-memory-database

I need to use HSQL transfer tool but can not find the correct place to run it. I read some threads says that it is in the tool menu in Database Manager. But it is disabled on mind. Then I futher find out that I will need to build it myself. After I build it and get 'hsqldbutil.jar' in the lib folder, the menu is still not enabled. Any idea what I should do now to have it run on my machine?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jar in the classpath of the Java command you use to start the DatabaseManager. See this chapter of the Utilities Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/dbm-chapt.html

The command looks like this:

```
java -cp /path/to/hsqldb.jar;/path/to/hsqldbutil.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager
```

Comment: According to the doc, haqldbutil.jar no longer included in the distribution, so you need to the steps in my bulletvpointed answer below.

Answer (score 1):

1. set up your ANT, and run the following build in the build folder of your hsqldb installation folder
2. ant hsqldbutil
3. go to the lib folder and run the following,
4. java -cp hsqldb.jar;hsqldbutil.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager

You will now see the grayed out "Tools" menu enabled, and select the tool of your choice.

Comment: To add some precisions, you have to be in the `build` directory in step 2 to run `ant hsqldbutil`. And in step 4, the exact command is `java -cp hsqldb.jar:hsqldbutil.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager`